# Remove node at the TAIL Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

All, I'm creating a function that would remove the tail from a linked list. And My function works fine for just one iteration but it doesn't for subsequent ones. 
Could anybody shed some light?

Thanks

```
int List::removeAtTail(){
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Node cannot be deleted from an empty linkedList" << endl;
    }

    if(curr->next= NULL)
    {
        curr->next=curr;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

And also, if I would like to return the element that I deleted, how would I go around at doing that?

Comment: Where are you deleting what??

Comment: In order to detach a node, you'd need the node that points at it -- ie: the previous node.

Comment: Wild guess: maybe it's from here: `if(curr->next= NULL)`

Comment: This function puts a loop in your list. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: @Cahu Another flaw, yes. Good spot!

Comment: In C++, a useful practice is to put the NULL check first in the if `if(NULL == curr->next)` that way, the compiler would have complained right away on your assignation mistake `if(NULL = curr->next)` For the second question you should post a different question if you don't find anything relevant on Google or other SO threads.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this can be done, following is one:

```
int List::removeAtTail(){

while(curr != NULL) {

   if(curr->next == NULL) { // depending on your implementation you might use Tail

      int temp = *curr;
      delete curr;
      return temp;

   }

   curr = curr->next;

}

return 0;
```

}

Notice how we iterate through the list until we find the last item.  At that point we store it in a temporary variable before freeing the memory.  Lastly we return the value stored in the temporary variable.

Comment: `temp` has become an invalid pointer after deleting `curr`

Comment: Good catch, I'll update the code.